# Sort selected references within brackets in main text with Lyx and JabRef

Tags: lyx, sorting, jabref

I'm using Lyx and JabRef and it appears that when citing multiple references within a bracket the default sorting within the brackets is alphabetically. However, I would like to sort them by their appearance in the document. I can move titles up and down in the citation settings and sort them by hand [image]

Is there an automated way of doing this?

Comment: Hi, welcome. Sorting depends on the bibliography style, the `unsrt` style for example sorts by appearance.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Thanks for your reply! I believe I'm using unsrt and when looking at the output indeed the references are sorted by appearance at the end of the document, however in the main text (within the same brackets) they are sorted by name. My wish is to have them in numerical order within the brackets, e.g. [1, 2, 5, 7, 17] and not [2, 17, 5, 1, 7] (lets say that correspond to alphabetic order)

Comment: Oh sorry, I misread the question completely. Try adding `\usepackage{cite}` to Document -> settings LaTeX preamble.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Thank you, that worked great! Although to anyone experiencing the same problem I had to change the Bibliography style to Basic first. Document > Settings > Bibliography